# ¿Por qué la Lista <String> no es un subtipo de un <Object> Lista?

Tags: java

Pensé que la cadena String eran subtipos de objetos Objects pero:

```
ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<>() ;
ArrayList<Object> al2 = al1 ; //no compila
```

Comment: mmm.. no compila con que error? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una consecuencia de como funciona la herencia.

Si tenemos *List* con los métodos *T get()* y *void add(T)*, y una clase *U extends T*, entonces si hacemos

```
List<U> lista1 = new List<>();
List<T> lista2 = lista1;
```

*lista2* ha de tener un método *void add(T)*. **Pero el objeto lista2 es el mismo objeto que lista1, y lista1 solo tiene definido un método void add(U)**, no un método *void add(T)*.

Así que **`List<U>` no extiende `List<T>`, aunque U extienda T**.

Lo opuesto ocurre con el método *get*, si pudiéramos hacer una asignación

```
List<T> lista1 = new List<>();
List<U> lista2 = lista1;
U u = lista2.get();
U u = lista1.get(); // Ilegal! Entonces... ¿cómo puede ser legal la línea anterior?
```

pero no sabemos si *lista2* devolverá un *U* o alguna otra subclase de *T*.

La solución es usar wildcards

```
List<U> lista1 = new List<>();
List<? extends T> lista2 = lista1;
```

es legal. Esto nos índica que los métodos que devuelvan un valor devolverán un valor que extiende de T, así que se puede hacer:

```
T t = lista2.get(); (todos las subclases válidas son subclases de T)
```

pero sigue sin poder hacerse

```
lista2.add(new T()); (¿cuál es la subclase de T válida?)
```

A la inversa, si hacemos

```
List<? super U> lista3 = lista1;
```

se puede hacer

```
lista3.add(new U());
```

, porque sabemos que sea cual sea la clase de parametrización es una superclase de U y por lo tanto se puede substituir por una instancia de U. Pero

```
U u = lista3.get();
```

es ilegal.

Puedes buscar más información por los terminos "varianza" y "contravarianza" de genéricos.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> no es un subtipo de ArrayList<Object> porque ArrayList<String> no extiende a ArrayList<Object>.
```

String es un suptipo de Object porque lo extiende. Pero no en el caso anterior.

Si quieres convertir la lista de Strings a una lista de Objetos puedes usar:

```
ArrayList<Object> al2 = new ArrayList(al1);
```

Pero necesitas asegurarte que todos los elementos de al2 sean Strings. Por que de hecho pudieras hacer lo siguiente sin problemas de compliación:

```
ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList(al2);
```

O sea, crear la lista de Strings con una de Objetos. Pero si alguno de esos objetos no es String te va tronar en la ejecución.